# How to insert a full-page letter-size image?

Tags: image, tex

I have been trying to insert a letter-size image, but either this is cut because of the margins definition of the document style (book), or its size is limited to the specified margins.

Below is the code with which I have managed to obtain the size of the image:

```
...
\newenvironment{pagportada}{
\begin{list}{}{
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.3cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{19.2cm}
%\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}
%\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}
%\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}
}\item[]}
{\end{list}}
```

... and then call the environment to insert the figure as:

```
\begin{pagportada}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Portada}
\end{pagportada}
\newpage
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LaTeX:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
```

The `eso-pic` package will help you put objects on the background of pages. This will not respect margins: which is your need.

To put an image, include the following code on your page:

```
% First page
...

\newpage
% Second page
\AddToShipoutPicture{
    \put(0,0){
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{
            \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,
             keepaspectratio]{Portada}
            \vfill
         }
    }
}
\newpage
```

And the image is put at (0,0) page-coordinates and stretched (maintaining aspect ratio) onto the whole page, middle centred.

*(not tested)*

Comment: The code did work, thank you! However, it failed in exporting the corresponding PDF file when using the dvi2pdf command. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Correfct; this method only works with pdftex directly for creating PDFs.